# How do you make a site load faster when offloading is not an option?

Tags: performance

I have a website where I can't offload it any more, and it still loads some pages slow. Those pages are ones that can't be cached, like the cart or the checkout (Woocommerce). I have tried 5 different hosts, and it has behaved the very same way in every one of them: when the content can be cached, it is served sufficiently quick, but when it can't it is disappointingly slow.

The current host has 12 CPUs and 24 Gigs of RAM, of which 2 CPUs are dedicated to this site, together with 6 Gigs of RAM, IO 200MB/s, 2048 IOPS (CloudLinux). The web server is Litespeed. The limits are never reached, yet the site does not go any faster. Previously it was Apache, and before that it was Apache with NGINX acting as a reverse proxy. MySQL has always been version 8.

Should I try NGINX as the web server next, or what other solutions might there be to speed things up with pages that can't be cached? Removing plugins does work, but what I have installed is all needed. Any advice welcome.

Comment: If deactivating plugins has helped then you've discovered the cause. If the plugin is needed then you should raise any performance problems with the author or find an alternative. In my experience slow code on the cart and checkout is usually because of plugins making synchronous HTTP requests to third party services, and a faster server isn't going to help with that. The only fix is to optimise the code so that HTTP requests aren't made unnecessarily, and when they are made they're made asynchronously where possible. This is all stuff the plugin developer needs to do.

Comment: You could start by adding an object cache (e.g. Redis), which usually improves WooCommerce performance instantly. Besides that, it might just not be better possible with your current setup, as Jacob already stated. (Issues might not only come from external/HTTP requests, but also a lot of database work. In this case, a stronger DB server could potentially help as well.)

Comment: I have experimented with both Memcached and Redis. I have currently Redis running - I should have included that in the original post - and it has helped to some extent. It seems like I should indeed be on the look for a DB server upgrade. Perhaps even getting an individual DB server would be a good choice?

Comment: This plugin helps optimize database queries, and may help. https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/  In conjunction with the redis object cache it has worked for quite a few large Woo sites.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.